# Difference between lazy var and let

Tags: swift

The following code works,  but when I change lazy var to let, it cannot work. I don't know why

```
lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.backgroundColor = .red
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    return cv
}()
```

the above code works but the following code has errors:

[image: Error]

Comment: It has errors because this is wrong syntax to declare constant properties.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is you use lazy initialization is when the initial value for a property is not known until after the object is initialized.

Also you do need to declare your lazy property using the var keyword, not the let keyword, because constants must always have a value before initialization completes.

Your data is not yet available, that's why is not working

[see more here](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/)

Answer (score 2):

From documentation:

> “You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var keyword), because its initial value might not be retrieved until after instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always have a value before initialization completes, and therefore cannot be declared as lazy.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.0.1).”

Check out this book on the iBooks Store: https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l